# Composer conflicts Magento 2

Tags: magento2, composer, conflict

What is the best way on resolving git conflicts with composer.json and composer.lock .

I have two extensions created from master installed through composer , one is approved to be merge , the other extension got the approved later on to be merged but while synchronizing files of master in the second extension got conflicts on those 2 files composer.json and composer.lock .

Im using *git*, *bitbucket* , *phpstorm* for this . Is there any fix on this (i don`t want to delete that branch and create a new one from master and install the second extension again. I want to fix the conflicts. ) ?

Comment: Can you show the conflict log so that we can investigate what is wrong?

Comment: Managed to fix it . Thank you @RendyEkoPrastiyo

Comment: HOW CAN I REACH YOU PERSONALLY VIA EMAIL, TWITTER..ETC. WANT TO DISCUSS WITH YOU SOME MAGENTO COLLABORATION. ME IS GEORGE, GEORGELAU63@GMAIL.COM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix the problem by comparing composer.lock and composer.json that has conflict with the composer.lock and composer.json of master. Took the rows i need to commit . Did a git push and now the conflict is gone .